# Stateless bean not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I wrote a stateless session bean.
Then a business method which adds up the balance to an instance variable is also included.
since it is a stateless bean it should not maintain the previous balance.

but it is maintaining it.

ie,

First I add 100 as balance,
Again I added 100 as balance.

According to theory it should give 100 as the result since it does not maintains the state.
But it is giving 200.

why?

I am using Netbeans IDE with Glassfish Server 3.0

Eg:

```
@Stateless
public class CalculatorBean implements CalculatorBeanRemote {
    double bal = 0.0;

    @Override
    public double Deposit(double parameter)
    {
        bal += parameter;
        return bal;
    }

}
```

In Servlet, I added,

```
@EJB
private CalculatorBeanRemote calculatorBean;
```

and inside the service methode, 

`out.println ("<br/><br/><br/>Deposit : " + calculatorBean.Deposit(100.0));`

Comment: Could you post some source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect to get a different instance of the EJB but that's not always the case.

EJB are usually pooled, that means when you are done using an EJB it gets back to the pool and another call might get the same object.

The container does not clean your members so you get 200 and not 100.

You can use PostContrsuct and PreDestroy to setup and cleanup the EJB you are getting.

In general you should not use any members in a stateless bean (exactly because of what you are seeing)

Comment: Does that means that the 200 I am getting is not always the same? Or some junk value

Comment: Yes that could be. Different containers works slightly different but in general the container holds a certain amount of instances, when you do a lookup or injection you get one of them, you don't know which one you will get.